# What's the best practice for keeping track of dynamically generated EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a quantity of items which I'm retrieving from a **database**. The user is expected to enter a serial number for every item, and the input values are to be posted back to the database. Thus, a dynamic `EditText` is to be generated for every item. I normally do it this way:

```
int itemQuantity;

List<EditText> listEditText = new ArrayList<EditText>();
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

for(int i = 0; i < itemQuantity); i++){

    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    linearLayout.addView(editText);
    listEditText.append(editText);

  }
```

Then I use `listEditText.get(index).getText().toString();` to retrieve values from each EditText.

Is this the right way of doing when considering performance and good practices?

Comment: This is completely normal. Though you can generalise it more by encapsulating EditText in a separate class and accessing it from there. Also be sure you dump all the views by assigning to null in onDestroy() to avoid memory leak.

Comment: Another alternative would be Making a RecyclerView of TextView. And take input for each item using a Dialog (with EditText). Its more efficient.

Comment: @PrinceBansal Using a RecyclerView of TextView would work; but wont it be irritating for users to have to input values for every item in a dialog, if the number of items is above 10?

Comment: This is very normal what you are doing.The only thing you should take care is dump the memory and avoid any memory leak.

Comment: @HarshMittal Wont the Java garbage collector take care of that for me?

Comment: Yes. Possible. But many apps have adopted this approach. 
Checkout this gist, I have used multiple EditText in more generalised way.
https://gist.github.com/princebansal/7bdac1e922033c5df84385cff2d6c4b8

Comment: Yes it will and you can also use System.gc() for it